# Should I put furring strips behind a wooden shower ceiling?

Tags: moisture

I want to install T&G cedar in basement shower ceiling. The walls are durock and Redgard and will be tile. Should I durock and Regard the ceiling then put the planks directly onto the ceiling? Or durock, Regard, furring strips,then planks? Or simply plank directly onto the joists? I'm worried about moisture.

Maybe I should tile the ceiling with woodgrain tile. However I was thinking T&G would allow for future ceiling access if needed.
Thanks.

Comment: I have installed a very good exhaust fan

Comment: Welcome. All information belongs in your question post, not down here in comments.

Comment: T&G, when properly installed, doesn't really make for easier access than any other material. If you need ceiling access, install a hatch of some sort, then cover it with the same material as the rest of the ceiling.

Comment: just a note about redgard... I would not use it unless you will have something in between the wood and the redgard.   The fumes are hidden behind thinset but I am afraid (never tested) that wood would let the fumes pass through and it will offput and smell horrible.   At the very minimum a couple of coats of oil based primer (which also offputs but at least it dissipates after a few weeks).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, if you need ceiling access, installing a hatch is the only practical way. T&G is not designed to be removed any more than tile, drywall or cement board.

**That said, whether this is practical depends on ceiling height.** If the ceiling is vaulted or 10'+ high, evacuating the moisture may be possible with one or more fans. If it is a typical 7-8' high basement ceiling, expansion from moisture will be an issue and ongoing battle.

Cedar is mold resistant but if it is not heartwood, that resistance is short lived. Western Red Cedar sapwood in Denver was mold resistant on my outdoor furniture for maybe 1 1/2 seasons. Eastern cedar is not much better. Most T&G cedar is mostly sapwood.

**Any wood product above the shower is going to have contraction issues** due to moisture. It will also wick moisture from the exposed side. I have done natural wood floors in bathrooms without issue until there is a leak (expected). Above the shower is way different than on the floor. Sealing against standing water is much easier than sealing against hot/warm steam.

My MIL insisted on T&G paneling on bathroom wall opposite shower. Maintenance due to constant humidity & temperature flux was a problem. I personally would do wood grain tile before natural wood.

**If you are going to insist on natural wood**, I would cement board the ceiling & then follow guidelines for installing the product as flooring over cement or damp locations. Typically this is going to be a combination of sealant & moisture barrier (more than just redguard) as well as outdoor rated plywood or OSB sub-floor. The wood planks will probably need adhesive on the backside & grooves and then normal tongue-nailed.

You will also need to account for periodic refinishing/sealing of the exposed side. This could easily be more frequent than sealing non-epoxy tile grout. Moisture will cause the wood to swell/shrink which will compromise the finish. Think outdoor decks...

Comment: Maybe OP can replicate walls/ceiling of an indoor cedar sauna? Thoughts?